# Deleting lines crossing particular features from another layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, select-by-expression

I have two QGIS layers. Layer 1 has a floor plan with an attribute field holding feature types, e.g., wall, corridor etc. Layer 2 consists only the lines drawn between door centroids. I want to query the lines in Layer 1, which cross a wall or corridor from Layer 2, then delete these lines.

How would this be done using QGIS?

This is what I have:

[image]

and this is what I want to have:

[image]

Comment: If you select wall lines by an expression, then use the select by location on your door centroid lines with that wall selection, will that select the door lines you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a virtual layer ([official documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers)), you can create a new layer then save the result as :

```sql
SELECT lines.*
FROM
  "Layer 1" lines,
  "Layer 2" structure,
WHERE
  NOT(
    structure IN ('wall', 'corridor')
    AND ST_INTERSECTS(structure.geometry, lines.geometry)
  )
```

or in QGIS create a selection in `Layer 2` with an expression like `type IN ('wall', 'corridor')`, select all features in `Layer 1`, and with the tool `select by location` ([documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-location)), you can **remove selection** from `Layer 1` that intersects **selected** features in `Layer 2`.

Then, toggle edit mode in `Layer 1` and delete selected features.

Comment: Thank you! It worked.